# Handling exception in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, bluebird

```
function ApiError(response) {
  this.message = 'API error';
  this.response = response;
}

ApiError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ApiError.prototype.constructor = ApiError;
ApiError.prototype.name = 'ApiError';

export default ApiError;
```

I have this custom exception and I throw it at some point, but when I try to catch it in promise like

```
import ApiError from './ApiError';
...
.catch(ApiError, (e) => {
    console.log('api error');
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log(e); <= this is undefined(in ApiError)
});
```

the error is delegated to generic catch with error saying that message cannot be assigned to undefined(`this=undefined` in ApiError), what am I doing wrong here ?

EDIT: The problem was actually the fact that I was not returning an instance of Bluebird promise, but Node `Promise`(using `fetch`), I resolved it by wrapping fetch inside Bluebird `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: You'd better [post an own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead of editing the solution into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the fact that I was not returning an instance of Bluebird promise, but ES6 Promise(using fetch), I resolved it by wrapping fetch inside Bluebird Promise.resolve.

Comment: It seems hard to see how this issue would, by itself, lead to the error you describe in the question.

Comment: It leads to the error just because the native promises does not support typehinting the error type as first argument. That's why I get the error, because instead of checking if type of error is matching the native promise is trying to call the first argument and it calls the constructor of error without `new` so it leads to `this` being undefined in this case.

Comment: OK, kind of hard for us to have ever had any idea of this since you didn't disclose where the promise in question is created or rejected.  Why don't you at least add this extra explanation to your answer so your answer at least explains why you were getting the error you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

That error sounds like you aren't creating the instance of your `ApiError` object properly.

When you throw one of your errors, it should be:

```
throw new ApiError(xxx);
```

Note, the `new` that must be used.  The specifics of your error make it appear like you aren't using the `new`.

---

Alternatively, you could change the implementation of your `ApiError` constructor so that you could do;

```
throw ApiError(xxx);
```

But, you'd have to change ApiError to detect whether it was called with `new` or not and if not, then call `new` itself.

```
function ApiError(response) {
  if (!(this instanceof ApiError)) {
      return new ApiError(response);
  }
  this.message = 'API error';
  this.response = response;
}
```

Or, in ES6, you can use the `new.target` option:

```
function ApiError(response) {
  if (!new.target) {
      return new ApiError(response);
  }
  this.message = 'API error';
  this.response = response;
}
```

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit, you could detect whether it was called with `new`  with `this instanceof ApiError`, or in es6 with `new.target` (e.g. `if (!new.target) return new ApiError(response)` in the constructor)

Comment: @redbmk - Added those options.